# Is calling method of a class rather than an object of that class/type valid or a thing?

Tags: python, class, methods

To explain inheritance in Python, the author of a book (by Charles Dierbach) uses the following example of an exploded string class, which takes a string as input (`Hello World`) and outputs it as `H e l l o  W o r l d` without quotes when the `explode()` method of the subclass is called:

```
class ExplodedStr(str):
   def __init__(self, value = ''):
       str.__init__(value)
...
```

**Question:** The `str.__init___(value)` method of class is called rather than method of an object of that type/class. Should I just take this for granted (memorize it) and proceed, or is there a logic?

Comment: This is actually the equivalent of `super().__init__(value)` and it's actually not necessary

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain more?

Comment: It's not necessary because strings in Python are immutable and the value of immutable types is set in their `__new__()` method, not their `__init__()` method.

Comment: Also note, in general, `some_instance.some_method()` is equivalent to `SomeClass.some_method(some_instance)` (although not *exactly* but pretty much)